# How to exit Ex mode in vim (typing :visual does not work)

Tags: vim

I don't know how to exit Ex mode in vim. I think I tipped something that is still open and don't know how to close it:

```
<uments/LeWagon/Teacher_Lessons theory.rb                                                                                                                                            
Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:w
"theory.rb" 22L, 472C written
:i
:w
:q
visual
:visual
visual
^W^W^W^W^K^W
kj^W
exit
:exit
:visual
visual
```

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You got into insert mode inside Ex mode with `:i`, so you need to leave it with a line containing only a period:

```
.
```

Then `:visual` will work.

In other words: <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `^C` should also work, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.