# Using vim keys in zsh terminal, how to exit "excute:_" mode?

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh, vi

I have recently switched to vim style key binding for my terminal by placing `set -o vi` in my .zshrc file. When using it I find myself in this "excute:_" mode after pressing `Esc` and then `:` , the terminal then looks like this:

```
[I] ➜ 
execute: _
```

What is this mode and how do I exit it?

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656164/how-to-exit-ex-mode-in-vim-typing-visual-does-not-work) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43003/using-vi-keys-to-edit-shell-commands-in-unix) for answers to no avail. I also asked in the vim stack exchange and got told to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's called the vicmd mode. You can execute commands from the ZLE ([Zsh Line Editor](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Editor-Functions-Index.html)).
For example, you can type `ed` then `TAB` for completion which should write `edit-command-line` and if you run it, it will open your editor to edit the current line (as the name suggest).

You can go back to normal mode with `ctrl` + `c`

Answer (score 0):

It's called `command` mode. `vicmd` mode mentioned in the first answer is zle mode which is like vim's normal mode. `command` mode is mode in which zle waits for a name of a zle widget which is then executed, hence the name. It's has TAB completion so if you enter `execute:`  mode, write "history" and press TAB, completion menu with all loaded widgets which name starts with history will show up.