# Got stuck in ex mode after typing :i accidentally

Tags: vim, neovim

So this might sound funny but a lot of times a press the wrong command in Ex mode and end up getting stuck

today this happened :

[image: me getting stuck image]

After pressing `:i` nothing seems to work, any clue what am I doing wrong? Haven't saved the file yet, so I really don't want to quit it.

Comment: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656190/14467607)

Comment: Why use Ex mode if you don't know how to use ex?

Comment: @romainl new people have to somehow learn working with it.

Comment: Well yes and no. *Yes*, ~~newbies have~~ everyone has to learn how to use their tools. *No*, they shouldn't press buttons at random to do so. Again, there is no point in using Vim's Ex mode if you are not already familiar with ex.

Comment: @romainl surely you can sympathise with someone accidentally pressing the wrong key combination? Simply hitting gQ will take them into ex mode, and they might not realize how to exit, so they might try something like :i which only makes them more stuck, since the hint "type :visual" stops working then.

Comment: Duplicate question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656164/how-to-exit-ex-mode-in-vim-typing-visual-does-not-work

Comment: @payloskollias in future please do not include images of text or code, it is against the stack overflow guidelines, because you cannot copy paste from an image, screen readers cannot read images etc. I have 2 blind programmer friends who are able to answer stack overflow questions just fine, provided there are no images in the question.

Comment: @StunBrick no, i can't. When you enter Ex mode, "accidentally" or not, you get the "Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to normal mode." message, that a) is very clear about what to do to leave Ex mode and b) doesn't even go away as you type commands. If Vim tells you to type `visual` to go back to normal and you type `i`, then you should check your priorities a bit.And even then, `:i` is well documented so there is really no point asking.

Comment: @romainl I don't want to start an argument in the comment section so this will be my last comment on the subject, but I think it's perfectly reasonable for a newer user to be confused, or forget which command to use, even if there are hints on the screen. Banner blindness is common, in our daily lives we are hit with so many popups, adverts, warning messages and errors that sometimes the mind skips important things too. You can see that the OP tried entering insert mode, entering vi and then on the third attempt realized `:visual` was what they wanted, but it was too late. Now they've learned.

Comment: This is getting sillier and sillier by the minute.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally entered insert mode whilst inside ex mode.

1. Exit the insert mode by typing a single line containing only
   `.`
   and hit enter
2. Exit ex mode by typing
   `:visual`
   and hit enter

now you should be back to normal vim.